# How to use my own icons in vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4, icons, datetimepicker

I need to change the icons in the datepicker I am using in a vue component.

Here the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker

In my main.js I have (the relevant parts):

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import 'pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css'
import datePicker from 'vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker'
import '@/icons' // icon
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(datePicker)
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))
```

This import `'@/icons'` is for my own folder containing the svg code for each icon. It is working fine all over the app.
Following in the code (still main.js):

```
jquery.extend(true, jquery.fn.datetimepicker.defaults, {
  icons: {
    time: '<svg-icon icon-class="plus-circle" class="plus" />',
    date: 'tools',
    up: 'run',
    down: 'pdf',
    previous: 'tree',
    next: 'user',
    today: 'form',
    clear: 'table',
    close: 'eye'
  }
})
```

I've changed the default icons with my own (just with their names -random, as I normally do in the rest of the app, or with the html tag), but it doesn't work.
Also, this part is not really clear to me `jquery.fn.datetimepicker.defaults,`. Following the imports I should use `datePicker`, but if I do it, the console says it is not defined.

So I actually don't know for sure if the problem is using my own icons, or if I am doing something wrong somewhere else in the code.

Following the docs, in my vue.config file I've added this code

```
// plugin date time picker
config
 .plugin('provide')
 .use(require('webpack').ProvidePlugin, [{
 Vue: ['vue/dist/vue.esm.js', 'default'],
 $: 'jquery',
 moment: 'moment',
 jQuery: 'jquery',
 'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}])
```

inside the chainWebpack(config).

In the vue template where I use the datetimepicker component I have:

```
<script>
// Import required dependencies
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

// Import this component
import datePicker from 'vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker'

// Import date picker css
import 'pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css'

export default {
  name: 'NewActivity',
  components: {
    datePicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date: null,
      options: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
        locale: 'it',
        useCurrent: false,
        showClear: true,
        showClose: true
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried leaving the default ones, using glyphicons, using fontawsome and changing their names according to the last release but I never seen any icon showing.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks a lot.

x